# Error:Unknown host 'proxy.ssn.net'.in Android studio while loading a project

Tags: android, proxy, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

While loading project in android studio 3.1, build failed with error message "Unknown host 'proxy.ssn.net'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.".

After adjusting the proxy settings in gradle also it didn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Windows:

Go to : `File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy [Under IDE Settings] Enable following option Auto-detect proxy settings`

Mac:

Go to : `Android Studio > Preferences > Appearance & Behavior.. etc`

You can also use the test connection button and check with google.com to see if it works or not.

and after

```
File>invalid caches/restart >invalid and restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing in the gradle.properties file in the Gradle Scripts?. Comment those settings and sync the project.